# Django Html and plots to PDF

Tags: django, django-views, plotly, wkhtmltopdf, xhtml2pdf

I am using the Django application to generate some graphs using Plotly so

I tried to generate a pdf file of the following plots of
my HTML page is:

```
        <center> <p class="lead"><strong><em>&nbsp;All Plots&nbsp;</em></strong></p></center>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" >
                {{ sunburst|safe}}
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-md-6" >
                {{ sunburst2|safe}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my url.py :

```
    path('export_pdf/', views.export_pdf, name='export_pdf'),
```

and the views.py;

```
def export_pdf(request):
    df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
    fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
    df2 = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
    fig2 = px.line(df2, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')

    chart = fig.to_html()
    chart2 = fig2.to_html()
    context= {
        'sunburst':chart,
        'sunburst2':chart2,
        }
    return render(request, 'Home/Reporting/part_pdf.html',context)
```

I tried some code from this page but I can't generate the file any help?

https://plotly.com/python/v3/pdf-reports/

are there any other methods for doing that (html page with plots and tables)?

All my best

Answer (score 0):

I searched high and low and could not find anything.  Hacked together a solution that worked very well for me:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio

labels = ['Alice','Bob','Carl']
vals = [2,5,4]

data = [go.Bar(x=vals, y=labels, orientation='h')]

layout = go.Layout(margin_pad=10)
fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)

svg = pio.to_image(fig, format="svg")
context["svg"] = svg.decode("utf-8")
```

and then in the template something like this

```
<div>
{{ svg|safe }}
</div>
```

The first solution was the one you referenced as well.  The quality was very bad though.  This solution is a lot more crisp.

I used it with weasyprint, but I'm sure it will work with other solutions as well.